# A bunch of UIGraphics methods were deprecated in iOS 17 with no clear replacement?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

I have a piece of code where I use the UIGraphics methods and it seems that the three methods that I was using are all deprecated.

This is a piece of Xamarin.iOS code but I am sure Swift users can help here too, can anyone help me out with what the new methods for these are I am trying to google for this but I don't seem to be getting any straight clues as to what replacement is for these methods.

The following three methods have been deprecated;

```
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, ScreenDensity);
    var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

The full piece of code is as follows, not sure if this helps though...

```
private UIImage CreateBufferImage()
{
    if (paths is null || paths.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var size = Bounds.Size;
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, ScreenDensity);
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

    context.SetLineCap(CGLineCap.Round);
    context.SetLineJoin(CGLineJoin.Round);

    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        context.SetStrokeColor(path.Color.CGColor);
        context.SetLineWidth(path.Width);

        context.AddPath(path.Path.CGPath);
        context.StrokePath();

        path.IsDirty = false;
    }

    var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731227

Comment: In Swift you would use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` instead of the older `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and related functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should now use the [`UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uigraphicsimagerenderer?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) API to draw images.

```
var renderer = new UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size, new UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat {
    Opaque = false,
    Scale = ScreenDensity
});
```

You should pass in an `Action<UIGraphicsImageRendererContext>` to [`CreateImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uigraphicsimagerenderer.createimage?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to draw your image. The image will be returned by `CreateImage`.

```
var image = renderer.CreateImage(imageContext => {
    // if you want a CGContext, you can get that from the CGContext property
    var cgcontext = imageContext.CGContext;

    // drawing code here...
});
```